# Concurrency in Amazon S3

Tags: c#, concurrency, locking, amazon-s3, distributed

I'm currently building a system where S3 will be used as a persistent hash-set (the S3 URL is inferred from the data) by lots of computers across the Internet. If two nodes store the same data then it will be stored using the same key and it will therefore not be stored twice. When an object is removed I need to know whether some other node(s) is using that data as well. In that case I will not remove it.

Right now I've implemented it by adding a list of the storing nodes as part of the data written to S3. So when a node is storing the data the following happens:

1. Read the object from S3.
2. Deserialize the object.
3. Add the new node's id to the list of storing nodes.
4. Serialize the new object (the data to store and the node-list).
5. Write the serialized data to S3.

This create a form of idempotent reference counting. Since requests over the Internet can be quite unreliable I don't want to just count the number of storing nodes. That's why I'm storing a list instead of a counter (in case a node sends the same request >1 times).

This approach works as long as two nodes are not writing simultaneously. S3 doesn't (as far as I know) provide any way to lock the object so that all these 5 steps become atomic.

How would you solve this concurrency issue? I'm considering implementing some form of optimistic concurrency. How should I do that for S3? Should I perhaps use a completely different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider first separating the lock list from your (protected) data. Create a separate bucket specific to your data to contain the lock list (bucket name should be a derivative of your data object name). Use individual files in that second bucket (one per node, with the object name derived from the node name). Nodes add a new object to the second bucket before accessing the protected data, nodes remove their object from the second bucket when they're finished.

This allows you to enumerate the second bucket to determine if your data is locked. And allows two nodes to update the lock list simultaneously without conflict.

Comment: I like the idea! It works for the writes, since S3 now has read-after-write consistency but I guess we still stand the risk of not deleting an object, since it doesn't have read-after-delete consistency.

Answer (score 3):

To add onto what amadeus said, if your needs aren't relational, you can even use AWS' SimpleDB, significantly cheaper.

Comment: Thanks, but the size of our objects (a couple of MB/object) makes SimpleDB a very expensive (maybe even impossible) option.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Amazon S3, but here is my persistence-ignorant suggestion.

1. Can you use command query segregation? Will be nice to separate reads from commands, as this check will occur only for the command (DELETE) and you don't need it for reads (if I got it correctly).
2. If there is no native support for such synchronisation, then your own rolled solution might be a bottle neck in terms of high load (which can be solved by [3] and [4]). All your DELETEs should go through a central place - request queue.
3. I would do a dedicated service (like WCF) with a concurrent request queue in it. Every time you need to DELETE an object, you will enqueue an item. The service, in it's own pace, will dequeue the item and do all your 5 steps as a single transaction. This may introduce some delays, which however may not be visible if the system is read-heavy.
4. If the system is write-heavy you may need to add workers that help to dequeue the request from the queue [3]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, using some sort of queuing is one way to solve it (e.g. using SQS). However, I would have to to it for writes as well, not just deletes (otherwise some added nodes might get lost). My concern with this is that it might become either too expensive (SQS becomess an extra cost) or that the throughput is not good enough. Doing optimistic concurrency could possible solve that. However, I've never implemented anything like that before so I'm a bit worried that I'd introduce some weird bug (since it's hard to test concurrency-problems).

Comment: @Yrlec, I didn't know Amazon has *SQS*. I was more thinking of a standalone *WCF* service on *MSMQ*, or *Mass Transit* or *NServiceBus*. The good thing about queueing - you can have it single threaded for queueing and multiple workers to dequeue it (each request is a separate atomic operation that doesn't share data, if that is possible). Maybe you can also try lock free techniques to perform the operations that needs synchronization - which is still a lot more problematic.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a good idea to separate the references from the resource.

You can build concurrency on top of S3 versioning.
Or let each referer/node create and delete its own lock resource on S3.
Or use Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS).

Comment: Thanks but we are doing this at such a large scale that we'd rather avoid using RDS (which has limited scalability) and SimpleDB (which has high I/O costs).

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own locking mechanism as a service on your ec2 and use it to synchronize accesses to S3. In this case you could store monitor counts in your S3 (separately or not)

Comment: In this case you should comply to Amazon services' performance in your implementation, or it probably will be a bottleneck in your chain